# ASP.NET Core Template 3.1.5 - serviceDependencies.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've just updated **Visual Studio 2019** and noted that in new **Template (3.1.5) of ASP.NET Core (MVC)**, there's **serviceDependencies.json**
Currently in ASP.NET Core docs there no point about this, and I wasn't able to find any in google as well.

I understand, that somehow will be possible to register dependencies in json, but didn't get whole picture. How to use it, and when?

with content:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "mssql1": {
      "type": "mssql",
      "connectionId": "DefaultConnection"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After spending a bit more time, I've found that this future is related to [**Configuring Azure Services and emulators using Visual Studio**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-azure-services-and-emulators-using-visual-studio/), and it's not yet documented [**Undocumented files related to UserSecrets appears on 16.6 Preview4**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1009236/undocumented-files-related-to-usersecrets-appears.html)

The goal is to describe services which will be used in Azure App Services, with possibilities of local emulations, for simplifying Development/Deployment routine.

Note from devblog:

> Starting with Visual Studio 16.6 Preview 2 the Connected Services tab offers a new experience called Service Dependencies. You can use it to connect your app to Azure services such as Azure SQL, Storage, Key Vault and many others. Wherever possible local emulation options are also available and more are planned for the future.