# Difference between Application Insights SDK (local) and Azure Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

In Visual Studio 2019 when I right-click my project and choose **Configure Application Insights** I have the option to add **Application Insights SDK (local)** or **Azure Application Insights**.  Unfortunately, the description and tooltips are the same for both options.  What is the difference between these two choices?

[image]

Comment: Could you please let us know how does this come out? like click which menu in VS?

Comment: @IvanYang updated question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First option Application Insights Sdk would only configure your project to add and use AI SDK. Second option would do that and help you create or select Azure Application Insights service instance and then add corresponding connection settings to your project.

Comment: The local option added Properties/serviceDependencies.json and Properties/serviceDependencies.local.json files to the project. A related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62069722/2157640 I have not found any good reason to keep them -- when the required NuGet package is installed, App Insights work and I can see no benefit in having the service dependency described in such a file. Having a Bicep ARM template is more useful and provides better insight into the app's infrastructure.